# kedro ipython, how to access the spark session

Tags: pyspark, kedro

I am able to load a spark dataset in a kedro ipython session.

- First, I configured the spark session as described [here](https://docs.kedro.org/en/0.18.3/tools_integration/pyspark.html).
  Then I launched a kedro ipython session with `ipython --ext kedro.extras.extensions.ipython` or `kedro ipython`
- Then, I am able to load spark datasets as defined in the catalog

```
    from kedro.framework.session import KedroSession
    from kedro.framework.startup import bootstrap_project
    from pathlib import Path
    import pyspark.sql
    #from kedro.io import DataCatalog
    from kedro.extras.datasets.spark import SparkDataSet
    import os
    os.chdir('/myproject')     
    project_root = Path.cwd()
    bootstrap_project(project_root)
    
    session = KedroSession.create()
    context = session.load_context()
    catalog = context.catalog
    
    test = catalog.load("mydata@spark")
    test.show(2)
    isinstance(test, pyspark.sql.DataFrame) # True
```

So there is a spark session correctly defined. question is, how to access this session object?
if I run `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`, I cannot confirm that this is indeed the session managed by Kedro, for example `spark.conf.get('spark.driver.maxResultSize')` throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException:` although this `maxResultSize` is indeed defined in my project's `spark.yml`

How to access the right kedro-managed spark session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you do `kedro ipython` (or use the extension) you should have `catalog` available as a global variable already and you don't need to create it yourself.

I have a feeling this will work:

```py
df = catalog.load('my_data')
type(df, pyspark.sql.DataFrame)
spark = df.sparkSession
...
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sparkSession.html

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859763/kedro-spark-session-configuration-values-not-found